# Optimise Build Time

Tags: optimization, msbuild, sql-server-data-tools

I have an SSDT project that contains (Among other things)

- 1115 User tables,
- 1209 Views
- 5304 Stored Procedures

Of those stored procedures, 3126 of them relate to a legacy DA system that is still in use. These procs are CRUD actions against the tables - and always against a single table. Unfortunately, these cannot be removed at this time.

When running a Build/Publish via MSBuild, this Database project takes ~10 minutes to execute. However, if I delete the CRUD procs, that time drops to ~2 minutes.

I've attempted to extract those methods into a composite project, but the overall time does not appear to be significantly changed.

The database project is making use of the `<CmdLineInMemoryStorage>True</CmdLineInMemoryStorage>` within the `.SqlProj` file - which has improved performance in the past.

Is there anything else that can be done to improve the build/publish time of a project with that many procs?

**Update: Legacy Procs**

Whilst the DA system is "Legacy", it's still being actively used. As such, the procs are subject to change, and there *are* new procs being created by developers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered doing a partial project with a DB reference to those legacy items already stored in a dacpac?  You could refer to that DB as "Same DB, Same Server" for its location and then only work on the newer things you need to manage in your project.  That seems like it would accomplish what you want without needing to re-build the static items.

Comment: Unfortunately, while the DA is "Legacy". Its still being actively used, so the procs are updated when the tables change. They do also occassionally create new procs. I wasn't clear on that in my question, let me update it. Otherwise, that may have worked out quite well.

Comment: I still think you might benefit from splitting it out into two projects. Unless you're referencing those new/changed procs, you won't necessarily need to worry about them as part of your release cycle and you can always make a one-off project for the legacy objects to maintain that and build that just as needed.